# Is it possible to measure Spinal Cord electrical activity over skin?

Tags: signal, biopotential

sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question.

I'd like to know the possibility and reliability of measuring electrical activity of spinal cord (specially the cervical region)

if it's possible do you know any research or project related to this, most of project I've seen is about measuring electrical activity of muscle contraction.

my goal is to decode the signals to control a virtual body. I'm a newbie if you have any information or resources regarding signal analysis that would be helpful

thank you in advance

Comment: There's a French group out of Bordeaux that is looking into this.  "A programmable bioamplifier on FPAA for in vivo neural recording" from BioCAS is paywalled, but start by reading this: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3767911/  this is related to processing, but I have seen the FPAAs from Prof. Hasler wired up to a electrodes in the spine of rats where they were "driving" the rats around.  The group was looking at the processing that was done in the spinal column, such as walking.  They also had some maps of this processing for cats as well.

Comment: If this is for people (including you) be **IMMENSELY** careful. Well isolated instrumentation amplifiers would be obligatory. | Do you need to measure the nerve signals? Can you instead telemeter head motion? |

Comment: There is some very weird and wonderful stuff happening around there - take due care!. I get low back pain. If I stretch my neck by applying moderate hand pressure under my head on both sides for say 20 seconds the back pain fades away. I had C4-C5 fusion surgery a year ago. Before that I had significant lower back pain - plus much worse in hands and feet under some circumstances. The operation instantly cured the low back pain for 6 months plus and it has only started to creep back a little of late. Neck stretching dispels it.  Achieving the opposite result is to be avoided !

Comment: @russell-mcmahon thank you for your comment. if by telemeter you mean something like image processing or point tracking then no, that won't be reliable for my purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: No, at least not with today's tech.

The signal to noise ratio is going to be very low, and there is no particular geometrical mapping of activity that you can take advantage of for surface recording.

There is a bunch of research, and mini consumer products, that takes advantage of the geometrical mappings in the brain to measure EEG to control cursors, robots, and such, with different levels of success.

There is also a possibility of grabbing the spinal cord signal at the ventral root, as it leaves the spinal cord, and thus much of the ongoing "noise" of the spinal cord is filtered out, and you're left with what's exiting at that level.  I haven't heard of this being done with surface electrodes (or even implanted electrodes, for that matter).

Impossible??  Well, many things are possible.  The way to go about doing what you envision??  Probably not.